# Custom app.config WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I'm trying to create a custom section in my app.config file, but when I run it, I get an error that I'm not sure how to fix. I've been reading up online on how to create these classes, but it appears I'm doing something wrong.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

This is code giving the error:

```
public void LoadConfiguration() 
{
    try 
    {
        // error is on the following line
        QueriesSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("queries") as QueriesSection;
        Assert.IsNotNull(section, "section is null");

        QueriesCollection queries = section.Queries;
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, queries.Count, "queries.Count != 0; actual = " + queries.Count);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The `App.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="queries" type="app.Config.QueriesSection, app" />
    </configSections>
    <queries>
        <add name="TableAvailability" sql="SELECT stuff FROM sometable" />
    </queries>    
</configuration>
```

These are the config classes:

```
namespace app.Config
{
    public sealed class QueriesSection : ConfigurationSection 
    {
        public QueriesSection()
        {
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("")]
        public QueriesCollection Queries 
        {
            get { return (QueriesCollection)base[""]; }
        }
    }

    public sealed class QueryElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true)]
        public String Name {
            get { return (String)base["name"]; }
            set { base["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("sql")]
        public String Sql {
            get { return (String)base["sql"]; }
            set { base["sql"] = value; }
        }
    }

    public sealed class QueriesCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection 
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() 
        {
            return new QueryElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((QueryElement)element).Name;
        }

        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType 
        {
            get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap; }
        }

        protected override string ElementName 
        {
            get { return "query"; }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the giant exception that:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'app.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=3
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at app.App.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\C15919\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\app\app\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
       Message=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for queries: The string cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name
       Source=System.Configuration
       BareMessage=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for queries: The string cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name
       Line=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionDefault(String configKey, Boolean getRuntimeObject, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
            at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
            at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
            at app.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\C15919\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\app\app\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 26
       InnerException: System.ArgumentException
            Message=The string cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name
            Source=System.Configuration
            ParamName=name
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty.ValidatePropertyName(String name)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty.ConstructorInit(String name, Type type, ConfigurationPropertyOptions options, ConfigurationValidatorBase validator, TypeConverter converter)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor(PropertyInfo info)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreateConfigurationPropertyFromAttributes(PropertyInfo propertyInformation)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.CreatePropertyBagFromType(Type type)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.PropertiesFromType(Type type, ConfigurationPropertyCollection& result)
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.get_Properties()
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.Reset(ConfigurationElement parentElement)
                 at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
                 at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithFullTrust(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
                 at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't mentioned the namespace correctly here

```
<configSections>
    <section name="queries" type="app.Config.QueriesSection, app" />
</configSections>
```

change it to

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="queries" type="app.Config.QueriesSection, app.Config" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a slightly different error:    InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'ClaimantWorkbookWpf.Config' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       Source=System.Configuration

Comment: please check the path of the file

Comment: What file path should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to test this but I would try the following. Change the ConfigurationProperty below

```
[ConfigurationProperty("")]
public QueriesCollection Queries 
{
    get { return (QueriesCollection)base[""]; }
}
```

like this

```
[ConfigurationProperty("", IsKey=false, IsRequired=true, IsDefaultCollection=true)]
```

I believe that should fix your error. but if it does not and you still have the following in your stack trace

```
InnerException: System.ArgumentException
        Message=The string cannot be null or empty.
        Parameter name: name
        Source=System.Configuration
```

Then it is most likely referring to the name value in the **ConfigurationProperty**. When I had a similar name cannot be null or empty I filled in the empty string

```
[ConfigurationProperty("namehere", IsKey=false, IsRequired=true, IsDefaultCollection=true)]
```

hope one of those helps.